# In Buck, how do I used the output of a genrule as a header for a cxx_library?

Tags: c++, buck

I have a `genrule` that generates a C++ header-file using a proprietary tool. The header is then used in a `cxx_library`. Looking at code from [this presentation](http://gerrit-talks.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/buck-intro.html#16), I have tried the following:

```py
cxx_library(
  name = 'my-library',
  srcs = glob(['src/**/*.cpp']),
  exported_headers = {
    'my_header.h': genfile('my-header.h'),
  },
  ...
```

However, it seems that `genfile` has been deprecated. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to specify the [build target](https://buckbuild.com/concept/build_target.html) of the [`genrule`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/genrule.html) in place of `genfile('my-header.h')`.

```
genrule(
  name='my-header',
  cmd='some_command.py',
  out='my-header.h',
)

cxx_library(
  name = 'my-library',
  srcs = glob(['src/**/*.cpp']),
  exported_headers = {
    'my_header.h': ':my-header',
  },
  ...
)
```